# Android build freezes on attaching unity3D profiler

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, profiling

My android game freezes when I attack the unity profiler to it. I'm using unity version 4.5.3 on OSX 10.9.4 to an instance of my game running on an android N7 running android 4.2.1. Unity is building the game using android tools r23.0.2, and android SDK 4.4.2. The min API level is 17. I'm not stripping any bytecode at all, and I'm running at full .net 2.0 compatibility. The device is attached to the laptop via USB.

My development builds deploy and run fine, and I can see the N7 in the profiler dropdown. But when I try to connect, the game on the device freezes. There's very little information in logcat, but this might be related:

```
W/Sidekick_GmmLocationProviderImpl(9312): Unable to bind to GMM NLP
W/ActivityManager(489): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.location.internal.GMM_NLP (has extras) } U=0: not found
```

The unity editor stays responsive but the profiler doesn't render anything. I've tried restarting unity and the device but no difference.

Any ideas?

EDIT: with the device on wifi, I can see both the USB and wifi connection on the profiler dropdown. Both seem to have the same freezing problem.

Comment: Have you tried on a different device?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have another. I have found this unity bug that suggests it's a widespread issue, possibly related to specific chipsets: http://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/while-using-android-profiler-on-tegra-devices-the-game

Comment: On a Galaxy S2, the same build will profile fine.

Comment: I just googled this, and found my own post. :) seems it's still broken in 4.6.1!

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different Unity3d build, the 4.5 is not too stable. Try to downgrade to 4.3.4 and check then.

Comment: Indeed rolling back to an older version of Unity seems like something to try. Unity has had issues in the past where profiling caused freezes and crashes.

Comment: Alas the reason I went to 4.5 in the first place was because 4.3.4 had so many broken bits - mecanim, 2D, etc.

Comment: I did also, then after countless crashes I came back. Lost my scene too many times.